# Using controller in view with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have simple function in one of my controller (members):

```
function action_data($array) { 
    $datamembre = DB::table('members')->where('id', '=', $id)->first(); 
    return $datamembre; 
}
```

I want use it in the view of another controller, I do this in my template:

```
 $datamembers = Controller::call('members@data', array($members_id));
```

Is there any better or proper way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best would be to put it into a Member model IMO.

Comment: This. It looks like data logic so it belongs in a model. Provide it to your view using a composer. You should not have any calls to controllers, models, et al.. in your view.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Use view composer http://laravel.com/docs/views#view-composers</strike>

```
View::composer(array('home', 'profile'), function($view)
{
    //
});
```

**update**

You can put the method in BaseController, all controllers extend it, so you could get this method in any controller/view. And make it static.

```
// in BaseController.php (L4) or Base.php (L3)

static public function action_data($array) { 
    $datamembre = DB::table('members')->where('id', '=', $id)->first(); 
    return $datamembre; 
}
```

In the view

```
BaseController::action_data($array); //L4

Base_Cotroller::action_data($array); //L3
```

Hope it works. Haven't tested it.

Comment: Thanks but composer is for view, i dont want include any view i want to use my function for display each username.

Comment: Updated. If it's want you wanted accept it as the correct answer so others can use it.